# How $\ln(x) = \frac{5}{6}$ is simplified to $x = e^{\frac{5}{6}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Hello I am trying to understand *how my professor simplified* this:

$$\ln(x) = \frac{5}{6}$$

into this:

> $$x = e^{\frac{5}{6}}$$

Comment: The exponential function $x\mapsto e^x$ is the inverse function of $x\mapsto\ln(x)$. That is, you have both $e^{\ln(x)} = x$ (which was used here) and $\ln(e^x) = x$.

Comment: The natural logarithm is by definition the inverse of the exponential function with base $e$.

Comment: I always think of $\ln(x)$ as the answer to the question, "What power do I have to raise $e$ to, to get $x$?" So if $\ln(x) = 5/6$, then "$5/6$ is the power you need to raise $e$ to, to get $x$" hence the translation.

Comment: Thank you @pjs36. You've answered my question.

Comment: It's the definition.  $e^a=b \iff \ln b =a $.  Those statements both mean the exact same thing.

Comment: Wait guys... I know not knowing something is not a crime so I don't downvote such questions. But upvote is given to questions which are useful or show research effort. So please make a good use of it, at last it is your choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since my comment was well-received:

I always think of $\ln(x)$ as the answer to the question, "What power do I have to raise $e$ to, to get $x$?" So if $\ln(x) = 5/6$, then "$5/6$ is the power you need to raise $e$ to, to get $x$" hence the translation.

---

In my experience, people who successfully deal with logarithms are successful at *translating* back and forth between logarithmic and exponential equations; I hesitate to write the general equation

$$\log_b(x) = y \text{ if and only if } b^y = x,$$

but it really is just the equation-version of the idea that $\log_b(x)$ is the answer to the question, "What power do I have to raise $b$ to, to get $x$ (or more conversationally, *the thing inside the logarithm*)?"

This all comes from the idea that $\log_b(x)$ is defined to be the inverse of the base-$b$ exponential function, $y = b^x$, if you remember that inverse functions simply switch inputs and outputs.

In the case of the exponential-logarithmic inverse, it's nice to think in terms of

$$\text{base}^\text{exponent} = \text{result} \longleftrightarrow \log_{\text{base}}(\text{result}) = \text{exponent};$$

logarithmic functions take the output from raising something to a power, and give you back the power. In a sense, I'm suggesting you think in terms of units/labels for the pieces of the equation -- that way you'll never be caught plugging an exponent into a logarithm, because the 'units' don't match!

Answer (score 6):

The [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) is the log in base $e$ where $e$ is the [Euler number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

> $$\ln(x) := \log_e(x)$$

You have [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Definition) of logarithm and you can just apply to it.

> $$\log_\color{blue}e(\color{red}x) = y \Leftrightarrow \color{blue}e^y = \color{red}x$$